# Better way to compute commutator subgroup of $A_n$ for $n\geq 5$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

I want to show that $[A_n,A_n]=A_n$ for $n\geq 5$.
Clearly $[A_n,A_]\leq A_n$. But to show the reverse inclusion I have an answer which involves too much "calculation"(As $A_n$ is generated by the three cycle therefore writing a three cycle as a commutator of two three cycles). Does anyone know any simple way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  Compute the commutator of the 3-cycles $(abc)$ and $(cde)$, where $a, b, c, d$, and $e$ are all distinct.